# Mobile Navigation Overlay issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I've got a responsive website which works as required so far but when the mobile nav is set all the links on my site aren't clickable or can hover over. I'm assuming it's an issue regarding the width and height of the nav background but i want the mobile nav to fill the screen when it's clicked.

See my code below;

```
nav.mobile {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 6.2rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 3;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(41, 70, 97, 0.2);
  transform: translate(0, -160px);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  padding-bottom: 0rem;
  opacity: 0; 
  //added this for demo only. On a mobile device max width is not necessary.  
}
nav.mobile--open {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  opacity: 1; 
}
nav.mobile ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0; 
}
nav.mobile li.link {
  font-family: "Colfax-Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 1.5rem 0 0.5rem 1.5rem; 
}
nav.mobile li.link a {
  color: $blue_bg;
  display: block; 
  text-decoration: none;
  &:hover{
    color: $green;
  }
}
```

any help is really appreciated!

Comment: plz send me demo link

Comment: Can you create a fiddler or post an image?

Comment: http://oakwood-services.co.uk/dev/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding height in `vh` unit

```
nav.mobile--open {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  opacity: 1; 
   height: 100vh;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: this works however it allows the user to scroll still - it needs to be fixed over the top so you cant scroll.